# Redirecting domains in WordPress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain

I have a Wordpress Multisite and have subdomains for each language.

I have managed to implement the subdomains es.mysite.com and en.mysite.com and they work perfect.

I would want now that if the user types www.mysite.com or mysite.com redirect him to es.mysite.com or en.mysite.com depending of the language of his browser.

I have been searching but couldn't find this particular case.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you: [PHP language detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352130/php-language-detection)

Use PHP language detection, based on the language, redirect the user to the appropriate URL.

Simple example (after you parse):

```
if($language == 'en-us')
{
    header("Location: http://en.mysite.com/");
}
elseif($language == 'fr-fr')
{
    header("Location: http://fr.mysite.com/");
}
```

**Update:** I think reading this might help you out a bit. Not sure if you have done this already... http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress

Comment: I have done this before but the problem is that wordpress changes the index.php file so if i put this then the subdomains es.mysite.com or en.mysite.com stop working.

Comment: I added a link in my answer that I think may help you out. Not sure if you have read it yet.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin looks like what you're looking for: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/geographical-redirect/

Comment: Thanks i will try it and tell you the results :)