# What is the best solution to redirect users based on browser language

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to redirect users based on browser language, I figured out how to do this here, it works fine. The question is how can I use this code for other English language navigator too, for example: /en-AU/, /en-BZ/, /en-CA/, /en-CB/, /en-GB/, /en-IE/, /en-JM/, /en-NZ/, /en-PH/, /en-TT/, /en-ZA/, /en-ZW/. Also it's not cross-browser. Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
if(preg_match('/en-US/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
$_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
header("location:http://domain.com");
}else{
$_SESSION['lang'] = 'ru';
header("location:http://domain.com/ru");
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Language Detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352130/php-language-detection); tl;dr: use `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`.

Comment: @Amadan, thank you for your answer. I tried to use by that instructions but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you can use "polylang" plugin which allow your to create multiple
>   language on same WordPress.
>
> only you need to switch the post on admin panel and on front you can
>   redirect to same post content when switch the language.
>
> and you can also use 'ne_NP.mo' and 'ne_NP.po' file to convert other
>   wordpress default content or title. you need  and you need to generate
>   'ne_NP.mo' file from 'ne_NP.po' using 'mo' file generator
>
> you can get he current language code as below

```
<?php  echo $curLang = substr(get_bloginfo( 'language' ), 0, 2);?>
```

> and check the language and redirect accordingly