# How to replace translator instance in slim framework?

Tags: php, laravel, twig, translation, slim

I'm using slim and Laravel's illuminate/Translation. I'm new to all of this, I've found a solution to translate my pages but I'm having a problem when I'm trying to pass another translator instance(to change the translation of the page) to the container during run time to change the translation.
Here's what I'm doing: 
I have a navigation bar with Twig like this:

```
<li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">lang<span class="caret"></span> </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="{{path_for('en')}}" >english</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="{{path_for('fr')}}">french</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
```

and a language controller where I set the new instance of the translator to the container:

```
  public function getFrench($request, $response){
    $loader = new FileLoader(new Filesystem(),  __DIR__ . '/../resources/lang' );
     // Register the french translator (set to "en" for English)
    $translator = new Translator($loader, "fr");

    $this->translator=$translator;

   }
```

and this is how my container is set:

```
$container['translator']= function($container){

    $loader = new FileLoader(new Filesystem(),  __DIR__ . '/../resources/lang' );
     // Register the french translator (set to "en" for English)
    $translator = new Translator($loader, "en");

    return $translator;
};
```

**The view **  where I'm adding a translationExtension:

```
$container['view']= function($container){
    $view= new \Slim\Views\Twig(__DIR__ .'/../resources/views',['cache'=> false,]);

     // add translator functions to Twig
    $view->addExtension(new TranslatorExtension($container->get('translator')));

    return $view;

};
```

I don't know if going about this the wrong way because I whatever I do I can't change the translation during runtime, I always get the translation that I set inside the container (in this case english), should I use globals instead of the controller way? and how would I go about this?

Comment: You should implement a middleware for that. In this middleware you detect the language (by header accept-language or route or session) and set the language into the translator object.

Comment: How do you do that though? I understand the mechanism of a middleware, but how do you relate the output from the view (in my case twig) to a different translator? taking into consideration that you have to add the TranslatorExtension to the view along with a translator instance to the container.

Comment: What should trigger translator switch? I mean, at what point in runtime you would like to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use the `Accept-Language`-header to detect which language a user want to see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352130/php-language-detection). This you can do inside middleware.

Firstly you should remove the extension-adding from the container

```
$container['view']= function($container){
    $view= new \Slim\Views\Twig(__DIR__ .'/../resources/views',['cache'=> false,]);
    return $view;
};
```

And then add the extension through a middleware, with the parsed language form the header:

```
$container = $app->getContainer();
$app->add(function (\Slim\Http\Request $request, $response, $next) use ($container) {
    $lang = $request->getHeader('Accept-Language');

    // $lang could be something like 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
    // see above link for more information about parsing it
    $parsedLang = parseLang($lang);

    $loader = new FileLoader(new Filesystem(),  __DIR__ . '/../resources/lang' );

    $translator = new Translator($loader, $parsedLang);

    // add the extension to twig
    $view = $container->get('view');
    $view->addExtension(new TranslatorExtension($translator));

    // execute the other middleware and the actual route
    return $next($request, $response);
});
```

Comment: I actually didn't take into consideration taking the default language from the browser, which I'm assuming is better than actually choosing it. Your answer was really helpfull +1