# Add static pdf to an email based on language - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I need to add to the attachment of the confirmation mail after successful checkout  static pdf attachment, but changing the source route of the file based on language he chose on my website. I use this code to attach the static pdf to the attachment:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'wphelp_email_files_woo', 10, 4 );
function wphelp_email_files_woo( $attachments, $email_id, $order, $email ) {
    $email_ids = array( 'new_order', 'customer_processing_order' );
    if ( in_array ( $email_id, $email_ids ) ) {
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $attachments[] = $upload_dir['basedir'] . "/2021/12/FORMULAR_NA_ODSTUPENIE_OD_ZMLUVY-1.pdf"; //Change the route and name for yours
    }
    return $attachments;
}
```

Comment: To get you started: https://www.phptutorial.info/scripts/languages.php or from here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352130/php-language-detection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_locale()` for get the website locale.

```php
if (get_locale() == 'en_GB'){
  $attachments[] = $upload_dir['basedir'] . "/2021/12/FORMULAR_NA_ODSTUPENIE_OD_ZMLUVY-1.pdf";
}
else {
  $attachments[] = $upload_dir['basedir'] . "/2021/12/otherfile.pdf";
}
```